# Orbeon - Email Properties

Tags: orbeon

I want to sent the document id of orbeon form to my email body, therefore I added the following property in my properties-local.xml file 
`<property  as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.resource.*.*.en.email.body"  value="{xxf:document-id()}"/>` but this will just display {xxf:document-id()} in my email body, need help please.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a feature yet. There is an [RFE](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2428) for it.